# Can’t see photos from camera on computer

Tags: nikon

I’m a beginner when it comes to the photography world. I bought a Nikon D3400 a few monts ago.

When I connect the SD card to the computer I can see (and view) the photos I’ve taken (.jpg format), but if I upload these photos to Google Drive (to send them to someone), a message shows saying that it can’t open the format of the image (even if I download it). Is that usual? If so, is there any program to convert the images to a format which can be read by the computer?

Thank you very much

Comment: When you say "a message shows", what shows the message? What do you mean "even if I download it"?

Comment: Can you share one of them with us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just solved it. The problem was the SD controller. The SD was connected and disconnected from the computer all the time automatically, which didn’t allow the pictures to be uploaded correctly to Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that you are sending "links" not actual jpgs.

My second guess would have been that you are shooting "raw" (NEF) and that what you were viewing was the embedded jpg thumbnail inside the NEF, but you stated that you are using jpg.

Comment: Just solved it. The problem was the SD controller. The SD was connected and disconnected from the computer all the time automatically, which didn’t allow the pictures to be uploaded correctly to Google Drive

Comment: Hi @N.Rufes. Would you mind writing your previous comment as a brief answer? That way, you can mark the answer as accepted (it's entirely acceptable to ask and answer your own question). Thanks, and welcome to Photo.SE! =)

Comment: Done! I'll be able to accept it in two days.